# show more content onclick using ACF

Tags: toggle, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create an ACF that has image, title, excerpt, and content.
I'd like to have it function like this page http://ashmitar.sg-host.com/our-team/

I'd like to pull data from ACF so my client can update. The text excerpt should be 50 words and the click the 'read more'(hide show less) and show full content (appended to excerpt)and show a less button to close back to just the excerpt with a link 'show less'(hide show more).

I can do it with javascript but it's not something that can be updated easily because the button ID has to be different for each team member, etc.

Using ACF, I'd have:

- Image field
- Title field
- excerpt field
- 'show more' link to open all content
- full content field appended to excerpt
- 'show less' link to close content
- excerpt field - 'show less' hidden

Anybody ever try doing anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

After lots of research, I came up with this solution. Hope it can help others:

```
<h2 class="team-member-name"><?php the_field('team_member_name'); ?> </h2>
<div class="post">
<div class="excerpt"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_field('bio_excerpt'), 50 ); ?></div>
<div class="whole-post"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_field('bio_full'), 250 ); ?></div>
<a href="javascript:void();" class="read">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery

```
$('a.read').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.whole-post').is(':visible') ? $(this).html('Read More') : $(this).html('Read Less');
     $(this).siblings('.excerpt').slideToggle(200);
     $(this).siblings('.whole-post').slideToggle(200); 
});
```